# creating new column with case_when when multiple conditions need to be satisfied

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am creating an indicator for rows which satisfy 3 conditions: 1) string is detected & 2) second character == 4 & 3) age >=18.

I don't understand why row 3 is getting flagged when condition 1 is not met.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  record=as.character(c("A4B", "AAA", "B45", "BBB", "B4A4", "CA4")),
  age=c(12,12,18,18,22,22))

code_flag <- c("A4", "BBB")

> df
  id record age
1  1    A4B  12
2  1    AAA  12
3  2    B45  18
4  2    BBB  18
5  3   B4A4  22
6  3    CA4  22
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    flag=case_when(any(str_detect(record, code_flag)) & str_sub(record, start=2, end=2) == "4" & age >=18 ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no")
)
```

Output:

```
  id record age flag
1  1    A4B  12   no
2  1    AAA  12   no
3  2    B45  18  **yes**
4  2    BBB  18   no
5  3   B4A4  22  yes
6  3    CA4  22   no
```

Desired output:

```
 id record age flag
1  1    A4B  12   no
2  1    AAA  12   no
3  2    B45  18   no
4  2    BBB  18   no
5  3   B4A4  22  yes
6  3    CA4  22   no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work:

```
df %>%
   mutate(
     flag=case_when(str_detect(record, str_c(code_flag, collapse = '|')) & str_sub(record, start=2, end=2) == "4" & age >=18 ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no")
   )
  id record age flag
1  1    A4B  12   no
2  1    AAA  12   no
3  2    B45  18   no
4  2    BBB  18   no
5  3   B4A4  22  yes
6  3    CA4  22   no
```